# RxJava and POST/PUT requests to the server

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to come up with a decent approach to sending updates to my server using `RxJava`. Getting stuff is easy with `RxJava` and the `MVP` architecture, however, I'm struggling a bit with updating things on the server. A simple example would be 'user changed something on their profile and I need to persist it to the server'. Previously, I would most likely create an `AsyncTask` to handle the `PUT` request to the server, or I would use an OkHttp callback feature.

In the new world, I'm thinking of using `Service` or maybe a `Singleton` class for dispatching such updates to the user. The idea is to make sure the subscription is not part of the UI lifecycle. I already have a `Service` defined and handling some stuff in the app, so extending it to dispatch things like user profile updates wouldn't be too much work. The part I'm struggling a bit is where do I keep my `disposable`s and when do I unsubscribe?

I don't really have any code to share, but let's say I have a class called `UserDispatcher` which provides the following method:

```
    public Observable<User> dispatchUserUpdate(@NonNull User user) {
        return mRepository
            .updateUserProfile(user)
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui());
    }
```

`UserDispatcher` is created inside my `Service`, for now. So the Observable is returned to the `Service` and subscribed to in the `Service` as well (but this might be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unsubscription

Unsubscription in the Reactive world should not be different than in non Reactive world. so the consideration should be the same which is the lifecycle of `Service`, as opposed to `Activity` as you said, `Service` is not tied to the UI, and thus its lifecycle is much simple (started/stopped).
So you need to keep your subscription in the Service, which is the one dispatched the `Observable`, and to unsubscribe in the `onDestroy` callback.

### Service lifespan

Regarding the lifespan of the service, the unsubscription is only meant for cases where your `Observable` task didn't complete yet, and you don't want to leak resources. But, the normal path is, that you need to stop the `Service` after your `Observable` has completed.
You should use here a started service (not a bound one) that will stay alive until you will stop it (or the system kill it to claim resources), so it will not stop itself after you dispatch the `Observable`, you should hold responsible to stop it when the update `Observable` is completed.

### Recommended pattern - Scheduled Job

Generally speaking, using `Singleton` is not recommended, as it is not Android system component and thus, Android have no control on it like `Service`. things like rescheduling if work isn't done yet, get notified when the system is about to kill the `Service` etc...
As for `Service`, it's also not recommended anymore from `Lollipop` and up, as we have now the `JobScheduler` APIs, as the system is more strict regarding background processing (or other APIs that supports also older Android version like Firebase JobDispatcher).
But it shouldn't make much different, in `JobScheduler` API for instance you have the `onStopJob` event that you should unsubscribe at.

**Job Scheduler lifspan**

Regarding the lifespan with `JobScheduler`, it has the same pattern, when the `Observable` task is completed you should call [jobFinished()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html#jobFinished(android.app.job.JobParameters,%20boolean)) to signal the system that your job has done (`JobScheduler` uses Service to do the actual work).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out `JobScheduler`. I think I couldn't use it as it's not available in my target SDK level (16), but I think `GcmNetworkManager` is the same thing. But I'm still struggling understanding the pattern here. The `Service` will dispatch an API call, however, cause it has nothing else to do, it will shutdown and unsubscribe. Is there a recommended pattern to keep it alive until the the call is getting executed? But then it kind of defeats the purpose of unsubscribing.

Comment: JobScheduler is indeed for API 21 and above, as I mentioned there are other job oriented solutions like Firebase JobDispatcher (or Evernote android-job) that add supports back to old versions, internally they use different APIs depending on the version (I think the JobScheduler and GcmNetworkManager for the firebase case)

Comment: answer edited to answer also regarding the lifespan of the service.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I think I get it now. So basically I unsubscribe if something else has killed my service or stopped my job, otherwise stop the service or call `jobFinished()` when rx chain emits `completed`.